# Sortable, save position in database

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to save the changed position in the database. But I don't know how to handle the array-string with PHP.

I have the following code:

```
    $("#responds").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        $.ajax({
            type     : 'POST',
            url      : 'process.php',
            data     : {position: data},
            dataType : "html",
            success  : function(data) { 
                $('#responds').append(data);
            },
            error    : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(thrownError); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I handle the array-string with PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['position']))
{
    echo $_POST['position'];
}
```

The `$_POST['position']` contains the following data string:
`item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3`

How do I extract one element of this string, to put in the database? And must I have an ID inside `item[]`?

Comment: This is an array so u need to loop and get the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using php's [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) :

```
parse_str($_POST['position'], $pos_array);
print_r($pos_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

O parse you string containing data you can use PHP function [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). It is designed to do this job. Then  you can handle this data just like any other in the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the below code once you have the $_POST['position']

```
<?php 


    $postString = $_POST['position'];

    $newPOstStringStr = str_replace("&","",$postString);


    $arrvalues = explode("item[]=",$newPOstStringStr);

    print_r($arrvalues);
?>
```

The flowing code would give you the output in the flowing format which you could late on work with

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 3 )
```